# Is it ok to use string.length < 1 and omit nil check?

Tags: objective-c

In objective-c, one way to do it is

```
if (!string || string.length < 1) // string is empty
```

another is (I normally use)

```
if (string.length < 1)
if (array.count < 1)
```

Assumption is nil or empty string or zero-object array to the code logic is the same. Just wondering is it safe to omit the nil check?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is perfectly safe to omit the `nil` check, because according to the rules of Objective-C invoking methods or accessing properties on a `nil` object returns the default value of the return type.

In this case, the return type of `string.length` is a `NSUInteger`, its default value is zero, so `string.length < 1` will succeed for a `nil` `NSString` object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is alright to remove the nil check. As for the null string, length of the string will be zero. Thus, your check, `string.length < 1` will work. 
Therefore, you can safely use:

```
if (string.length < 1
```

Instead of

```
if (!string || string.length < 1) // string is empty
```

Same is the case for Arrays. You can safely use :

```
if (array.count < 1)
```